# Get substrings from that string format

Tags: php, string, substr

I have the following data and I can have 3 different cases:

Case 1:

```
"afield1" : "something1", "credentials" : [] , "afield2" : "something2"
```

Case 2:

```
"afield1" : "something1", "credentials" : [ ["root", "toor"] ] , "afield2" = "something2"
```

Case 3:

```
"afield1" : "something1", "credentials" : [ [ "admin", "support" ], [
"admin", "password" ], [ "admin", "123321" ] ] , "afield2" : "something2"
```

how can I get get the usernames and passwords?

Edit:

I found a silly way for the first case.. But the others are so compliated..  It can not be exploded neither on comma (,) or braket ([ ]) ...  Help if something knows how to explode correct or get the values from that thing...

Comment: use associative arrays with string splitting

Comment: if I am going to explode on comma (,) or braket ([ ]) it wont work.  I am not sure if I got your point. sry @MarkoMackic

Comment: This format is rather strange, where does it come from? It looks like partially changed `json`

Comment: you are correct, you'd have to think another way to parse it

Comment: @u_mulder it is from json, indeed.  Actually it is a log from Kippo honeypot and I need to analyze that thing....

Comment: What do you mean by `it is from json`?

Comment: It is an exported log data from mongoDB in json format. @u_mulder

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I did that. : mongoexport --db test --collection mydata --out data.json
I am pretty sure that it is json format.. Even splunk notice that it is on JSON format.  However, that silly brackets breaks all my analyzing code.

Comment: whatever,  =  was : . i changed that. however that not the case in the question. @SeanBright

Comment: What do you mean that it is not the case in the question? You aren't making any sense. If it is valid JSON (which is sort-of resembles after your edit), you can parse it with [json_decode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: if it's json, then you decode it to a native data structure, and your question becomes moot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `preg_match` and `preg_match_all` functions like in this code

```
$credentials = [];

$text = '"afield1" = "something1", "credentials" : [ [ "admin", "support" ], ["admin", "pass]word" ], [ "admin", "123321" ] ] , "afield2" = "something2"';

preg_match('/"credentials" : \[(.*?)\] ,/i', $text, $matches);
preg_match_all('/\[[ ]?"(.*?)"[ ]?\]/i', $matches[1], $matches2);

foreach ($matches2[1] as $match) {
    preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/i', '"' . $match . '"', $matches3);

    $credential = ['login' => $matches3[1][0], 'password' => $matches3[1][1]];
    $credentials[] = $credential;
}

var_dump($credentials);
```

On the ouptut you can see

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["login"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
    ["password"]=>
    string(7) "support"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["login"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
    ["password"]=>
    string(8) "pass]word"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["login"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
    ["password"]=>
    string(6) "123321"
  }
}
```

This code is working correctly for the others samples from your question.

Comment: however, a much more hard core code can be mulpiple explodes into chunks due to afield2 is always there.. So, if you explode in you 3 chunks the credentials and after that explode again and again base to ],[ and [ and ] it will work as well.

Comment: Or you could just use `json_decode` as has been pointed out multiple times.